# How to align Tweet, facebook and g+ buttons correctly?

Tags: css

Twitter and Facebook buttons alignment are okay but the g+ last button has a lot of space before it. I want all the three buttons together.

My CSS code:

```
div.social_sharing .g-plusone, .fb-like, .twitter {
    font-size: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And the html:

```
<div class="social_sharing">
   <div class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.mywebsite.com" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a></div>
   <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
   <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" count="true" callback="fire_multitrack" href="http://www.mywebsite.com"></div>
</div>
```

Better view:
http://jsfiddle.net/2vNKJ/

Comment: Are you sure this is all the relevant code? I had trouble reproducing in Chrome/Win7

Comment: The kind of trouble where all I could see were two blue dots: http://i.imgur.com/CZqt2.png

Comment: Weird. That is the relevant code

Comment: I followed your link -- I don't see the +1 button at all.

Comment: Yup. the g+ button are not showing for any reason. But I got it working just putting the g+ button before the facebook button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues for me

1. There is  a `.fb_reset` div, that must have `display: inline;`
2. And you must set the width for the facebook's `iframe`: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/2vNKJ/1/, or you can change the order: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/2vNKJ/2/, but then you'll want to change the width of the +1's `iframe`.

The problem with spaces is that there can be a lot of variations of button's content: different numbers and extra elements (for facebook's snippet), so it can be really hard to align these buttons horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find any way to remove the space before the g+ button, so I decided to put it before the facebook button and it works this way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the left margin?  Something like this:

```
   div.g-plusone {
      margin-left:0px;
   }
```

You might even try setting it to a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://forrst.com/posts/Placing_Tweet_and_Like_buttons_side_by_side-0Or

for wordpress blog can fix twitter link like this

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=<?php the_title(); ?>&amp;url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="iphonemods" data-hashtags="imod">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```